# How to integrate over a vector as input in R?

Tags: r

i have following excercise to solve:

```
Distribution <- function(f,a,b) ...

> f <- function(x) 0.5*sin(x)*(x>=0)*(x<=pi)
> F <- Distribution (f,0,pi)
> F(c(-100,0,1,2,pi,100))
[1] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.2298488 0.7080734 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

I need to write a function that calculates the distribution function of a given density function in the integral from a as lower and b as upper frontier.

```
Distribution <- function(f, a, b){
    function(x){
     if(x < a || x > b)
        {
            0
        }
    else{               
        Vectorize(integrate(function(x) f(x), lower = a, upper = x)$value)         
}
}
}
f <- function(x) 0.5*sin(x)*(x>=0)*(x<=pi)
F <- Distribution(f,0,pi)
```

This works for single values. But i need to write the function so that it accepts vectors as inputs. And i really don´t know how i can realize that. How do i check if the input is a vector? How do i output different values for it?
I am talking about R giving me the result like this:

```
> F(c(-100,0,1,2,pi,100))
 [1] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.2298488 0.7080734 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the Vectorize argument around you function definition (code untested):

```
Distribution <- function(f, a, b)
    Vectorize(function(x)
        if(x < a || x > b) 0
        else integrate(f, lower = a, upper = x)$value) 
    )
```